# Is it possible to pass a strongly typed model to a view/jsp page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In spring mvc, I noticed the models are passed as a name/value pair into the ModelAndView.

is it possible to create a strongly typed model and pass it to the view?

this way the caller in the view can't access a string index that doesn't exist.

Comment: Which view technology do you use? JSP?

Comment: Yes using JSP (jstl/etl)

Answer (score 2):

JSTL isn't type-safe - it's a scripting language. Furthermore, you'll need a sophisticated validation tool to check the correctness of the jsp.

So I don't think you are able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a significant limitation of Spring MVC.

With standard JSP, you can use

```
<jsp:useBean id="model" class="com.some.MyModel"/>
<body>
   Hello ${model.name}!
</body>
```

and modern IDEs will have auto-complete on the JSTL usage, and you can use functions like 'go to definition' in the IDE.

The name/value pair design of Spring MVC is only suitable for simple pages, and it is very hard to use and maintain when things get complex.

Also, you may wish to look at using JSF instead. Typed models, and very complete UI component set, when using libraries like PrimeFaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you would consider another view technology, check out [Scalate for Spring MVC](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/spring-mvc.html). It won't change your models but you declare your attributes in the header of the template files. In normal Scalate use, this will make calls to your template throw errors if the variables can't be found or are the wrong class.

Check [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/scalate/browse_thread/thread/584ee34920828089) for ideas. Sorry I don't have more info. Will be trying this myself.